# Error with maven build with assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I am getting below error while building tar.gz with maven with assembly plugin

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.1:single (default) on project RebateEngine: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.1:single failed: user id '50001255' is too big ( > 2097151 ) -> [Help 1]

Here is the full stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: user id '50001255' is too big ( > 2097151 )
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.failForBigNumber(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:623)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.failForBigNumbers(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:613)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:286)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.tar.TarArchiver.tarFile(TarArchiver.java:329)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.tar.TarArchiver.execute(TarArchiver.java:188)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:930)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:589)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:469)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
... 31 more
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's the type of user id ?

Comment: See FAQ: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#tarFileModes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working with org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`<tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>`

within the `<configuration>` block of the maven-assembly plugin

Tested with `v3.1.0`